# How to find Postgresql Json array elements of one table matches different column values of another table

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, join, jsonb

I have a table X with one column of type jsonb.

Jsonb contains json array - "cities":["aaaa","bbbb","cccc"].

Postgresql 9.4 provides jsonb operators to get json array elements using '->'

There is another table Y with column cities. 
Y 
a    b    cities 
                 aaaa 
                    bbbb 
                    cccc

I want to display 
select Y.a, Y.b from Y, X only if X.jsonb->cities is present in Y.cities.

Comment: maybe sqlfiddle? to see tables and be able to play with statement?..

Answer (score -1):

This is done with a lateral join over the `json_array_elements` (or in this case `json_array_elements_text` since y.cities is presumably text-typed) function. You didn't provide a full sample schema, so I'll hand-wave some untested SQL to give you the idea.

```
select *
from x
cross join json_array_elements_text(x.cities) AS x_cities(city)
inner join y on (x_cities.city = y.cities);
```

If you're going to use `json` you're going to need to get very good with lateral joins.

---

In general I'm seeing a lot of people using `json` where it's completely unnecessary and a simple relational modelling would be more appropriate. Think about whether you really need to do this. In this case it seems like if you must use an array, a native PostgreSQL `text[]` array would be better, but you should probably model it with a join-table instead.

Comment: Y.cities - varchar.   X.State is jsonb type. X.state has cities as json array. I cannot apply json_array_elements_text or json_array_elements on jsonb.

Comment: @SindhuShashidhar use jsonb_arra u_elements_text .

Comment: thanks Craig. jsonb column is of type json object. It has 6 json arrays. One of the array is cities. If I try to fetch all json arrays by jsonb_array_elements_text(X.state), it gives error "cannot extract elements from an object".

Comment: 1) {"state":["{"cityA":[],"cityB":[],"cityC":[],"cityD":[]}"]} How to get all arrays elements and compare with table Y?

Comment: @SindhuShashidhar Your sample data and description did not indicate that. If you can't solve it please post a new *accurate* question with sample data as CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements

Comment: What about **[PostgreSql : Json Array to Rows using Lateral Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709474/postgresql-json-array-to-rows-using-lateral-join)**?